# unable to seperate header classes. I get "does not name a type"

Tags: c++, header, include

I made a class with a header and a cpp and a main class. When doing so all is good! When separating a class that I will have 2 classes (header+cpp) and one main Class A (Board) does not recognize class B (IllegalCoordinateException) even though I inserted the include. This is probably a newbies question and I might lose some points, but I am stuck in finding my problem.

Here is my **working** code(stripped down to only the important parts):

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Board.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    Board board1{4};  // Initializes a 4x4 board

    try {
        board1[{3,4}]='O';   // This should raise an exception
    } catch (const IllegalCoordinateException& ex) {
        cout << "Illegal coordinate"  << ex.theCoordinate() << endl;  // prints "Illegal coordinate: 3,4"
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**Board.h**

```
#ifndef CIRC_H
#define CIRC_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct coord {
    int x;
    int y;
};



class IllegalCoordinateException{
    coord _coord;
    public:
        IllegalCoordinateException(coord c){
            _coord = c;
        }
        string theCoordinate() const{
            return to_string(_coord.x)+","+to_string(_coord.y);
        }
};


class xo{
    char x;

    public:

        char getChar() const{return x;}

        char& operator= (const char c){x = c;}

        xo& operator= (const xo _xo){
            x = _xo.getChar();
            return *this;
        }
        void clear(){
            x = '.';
        }


        operator char() const{
            return x;
        }
};


class Board{

    private:

        coord _coord;
        xo** board;
        int size;

    public:
        Board();
        Board(int v);
        ~Board();
        xo& operator[](coord c); // here is where I use "IllegalCoordinateException"
};


#endif
```

**Board.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Board.h"
using namespace std;


void freeBoard(xo** board,int size){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        delete[] board[i];
    }
}

Board::Board()
{
    size = 0;
    board = new xo* [size];

}

Board::Board(int v)
{
    size = v;
    board = new xo* [size];

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        board[i] = new xo[size];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++){
            board[i][j].clear();
        }
    }
}

Board::~Board(){
    freeBoard(board,size);
    delete[] board;
}


xo& Board::operator[](coord c)
{
    if(c.x < size && c.y < size)
    {
        return board[c.x][c.y];
    }
    else
    {
        throw IllegalCoordinateException(c);
    }
}
```

After seperation:

**main.cpp**
No diff

**Board.h** also cpp no diff

```
#ifndef CIRC_H
#define CIRC_H

#include "IllegalCoordinateException.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



struct coord {
    int x;
    int y;
};



class xo{
    char x;

    public:

        char getChar() const{return x;}

        char& operator= (const char c){x = c;}

        xo& operator= (const xo _xo){
            x = _xo.getChar();
            return *this;
        }
        void clear(){
            x = '.';
        }


        operator char() const{
            return x;
        }
};



class Board{

    private:

        coord _coord;
        xo** board;
        int size;

    public:
        Board();
        Board(int v);
        ~Board();
        xo& operator[](coord c);
};


#endif
```

**IllegalCoordinateException.h** // I also seperated in my code to .h and .cpp (but ofcourse there is no real diff.

```
#ifndef CIRC_H
#define CIRC_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"
using namespace std;

class IllegalCoordinateException{
    coord _coord;
    public:
        IllegalCoordinateException(coord c){ _coord = c;}
        string theCoordinate() const{return to_string(_coord.x)+","+to_string(_coord.y);}
};
#endif
```

When doing

```
$ g++ -g -Og -std=c++0x main.cpp Board.cpp IllegalCoordinateException.cpp
```

I get:

> Board.cpp: In member function ‘xo& Board::operator’:
>   Board.cpp:60:43: error: ‘IllegalCoordinateException’ was not declared
>   in this scope
>            throw IllegalCoordinateException(c);

How can this be? I mean I am including it in the Board.h so Board.cpp is supposed to recognize it!? I tried also to include it in Board.cpp and also make a forward declaration in Board.cpp but both were frugal.

Comment: `#ifndef CIRC_H` - how many times are you planning on using that fencepost. How about trying something else for your exception header. mk.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right, I use this automatically therefore I didn't notice it. I will check if this is the problem later , but it probably is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your header files have `#ifndef CIRC_H` / `#define CIRC_H`.

So when the first one is included (no matter which order), it defines `CIRC_H`, and when the second one is included, it gets ignored because the whole file is within `#ifndef CIRC_H`.

Solution: use a different macro name for each header file.